# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit-0.20

I am getting the following errors, I am using Restkit. How do I fix it?
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to xcode 5.1. When you (we) upgraded your project got changed by default to add 64-bit as a target, but your dependencies did not. Are you linking in a .a file, or have you imported  the source and made it build as part of your project? Best is if you can do the latter and have a .xcodeproj inside your project... then modify the dependency library so it has armv7 as a target too.